# Utility to store/cache all web pages and YouTube videos

Tags: browser, software-rec, browser-cache

I found myself in the following situation.

I'm travelling abroad with my laptop. I connect to a WiFi point and do a bit of browsing and play a YouTube video or two.

Then I disconnect and hop on either a plane or taxi.

Now I want to go back to some of the webpages I was browsing before and continue reading them, or watch some more of that YouTube video.

Unfortunately it seems like none of these resources are cached, or if they are, I have no idea how to access them.

Here's what I'd like:

A utility that starts when my computer boots and sits in the background, silently caching all the web pages that I view. Not only that, but also the resources such as YouTube videos.

Later, when I re-navigate to a site while disconnected, the browser automatically pulls the pages from my cache rather than giving me a 404 error.

Or I can click an icon in the system tray and see a list of all the pages/videos in the cache and view any that I like.

I'm sure Internet Explorer had a feature like this at some point, like "Offline Mode" or something. But these days it doesn't seem to work. Even when I select that option I still can't view pages that I'm *certain* I downloaded before.

So has the utility I'm talking about been developed yet?

Comment: What browser are you using. I know Firefox and Opera both have an offline mode (File > Work Offline) but your browser is not guaranteed to cache everything.

Comment: There are definitely Firefox plug ins that do this for normal browsing. Not sure about Youtube. However not sure what they are called. Have you searched the Mozilla plug ins/add ons web pages and your favourite search engine for an answer? Have you set your cache size high enough? Think the default size is usually only 50MB. I set mine to 500MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think MM3-WebAssistant does what you want.  I haven't used it, but based on the web page (http://www.proxy-offline-browser.com/) it acts as a web proxy between your browser and the web.  It automatically caches web pages and serves them from the cache when you're offline.
I'm not sure how it handles YouTube videos and it's garbage collection (cache clearing) is a bit of a mystery, but it is probably worth a shot.